# use stringbuilder to show asp chart control

Tags: asp.net

I want to create dynamic chart in my webpage.I use stringbuilder but i can not see a chart on the page.Can you please help how to do it?

```
StringBuilder builderchart = new StringBuilder();

builderchart.Append("<table>");
builderchart.Append("<tr>");
builderchart.Append("<td width=412 class=tdchart>");
builderchart.Append("<p>");
builderchart.Append("<asp:Chart ID=Chart1 runat=server><Series><asp:Series Name=Series1></asp:Series></Series><ChartAreas><asp:ChartArea Name=ChartArea1></asp:ChartArea></ChartAreas></asp:Chart>");
builder.Append("</p>");
builderchart.Append("</table>");
Literal2.Text = builderchart.ToString();
```

Comment: Is this all the code? You're doing nothing with the string builder.

Comment: the string you are appending is asp.net server tags which wont be understood by browser. Sir!

Comment: @AsilEris The final output of chart control is an image + lot of javascript code. You cannot use Literal control to display chart.

Comment: @AsilEris you are still using `asp:Chart` which browser doesn't know about. its not HTML. use only HTML tags OR chart if you want to render this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `StringBuilder` to instantiate a control.
You can download some Chart Control samples from the following link: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart